# How to wait on a thread to start?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

The way I am waiting on a thread to start is by creating an event, and when I create a thread, I pass it this event, and when the thread starts executing, it signals this event (which I am already waiting on). I have no problem with this approach, but I am wondering if Windows provides a special function for this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would I want to know anyway? I've only ever used threads in one of two constellations: a) the classic "consumer thread" which pulls tasks from a queue  b) "thread-per-task thread" which does some particular lengthy, possibly blocking operation (like loading a file). Problem (a) needs the worker thread to block, the main thread can post tasks any time and doesn't need to care, and in problem (b) the thread already knows what to do when it starts. In either case, the main thread only needs to be signalled when work has _completed_, not when the thread starts.

Comment: @Damon: A common scenario is passing temporary initialization information to the thread. In this case the thread needs to signal, when it is done reading the data, so that the owner of that data can release the resources. Transferring ownership is not always possible, and usually more complex than implementing startup synchronization. This is especially true, if the new thread runs inside another process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current solution is a perfectly good solution to the problem. You've no reason or need to look for a better solution. Certainly the threading API doesn't offer you any built-in mechanism so you do have to implement something. And what you are doing is a fine way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yup - it's a classic.